# Яна та Іванна: чи "тотожні" ці імена?

Tags: власні-назви

Питання, на яке досі не можу дати собі відповіді. Щодо імен **Яна** та **Іванна**, у [Вікіпедії](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%AF%D0%BD%D0%B0_(%D1%96%D0%BC'%D1%8F)) взагалі бачу, що варіант імені Яна - це **Яніна**.

Також у мене є знайома, в якої, наприклад, у паспорті пише Іванна, а називає себе Яна. Після мого зауваження на те, що це різні імена, вона все ж переконує, що ні.

В Інтернет-журналі для жінок [Жіночі примхи](http://women.in.ua/pohodzhennya-imeni-yana-yanina.html) теж знаходжу інформацію, що Яна = Яніна, адже друге ім’я взято в дужки.

На офіційному сайті Державної служби статистики України Головного управління статистики у Львівській област "[Імена](http://database.ukrcensus.gov.ua/dw_name/f_tl.asp?f_tl=%FF%ED%E0&Submit=%CF%EE%F8%F3%EA)", де подано тлумачення, походження i значення імен, читаю:

***Яна***

- походить від слова янус – імені древньоримського бога сонця і світла (латинське).
- жіноча форма імені Ян (західнослов'янської і прибалтійської форми древньоєврейського імені Іоанн, ***Іван*** – «милість божа») (слов’янське).  ***Янка***
- Божа благодать (давньоєврейське).

Таким чином тут додають ще і варіант ***"Янка***".

На цьому ж сайті подають окремо статтю з іменем [Іванна](http://database.ukrcensus.gov.ua/dw_name/f_tl.asp?f_tl=%B2%E2%E0%ED%ED%E0&Submit=%CF%EE%F8%F3%EA):

- життєва (слов’янське).  ***Іванка, Іва***
- життєва; від ява - світ життя; іва (золота верба) - дерево життя (давньоєврейське).

Отож ланцюг збільшується до таких "варіантів":

**Яніна, Яна, Янка, Іванна, Іва.**

Отже, це однакові імена? Наприклад, якщо в якихось одних архівних документах буде написано ім’я "Яна", а в інших - Яніна (йдеться про одну і ту ж особу), то відповідно до мовних норм вважатиметься що це одна і та ж особа? А також цікавить, у зв’язку з чим пішло таке розгалуження: одні імена на *ян-*, інші - на *іван-*.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Походження цих 2 імен (розглядатимемо на основі чоловічих імен від яких утворилися жіночі) знаходимо в [Етимологічному словнику т. 6, ст. 546-547 ст.](http://litopys.org.ua/djvu/etymolog_slovnyk.htm), а саме походження ім'я **ЯН** (**запозичене з польської мови**):
[image]

[Етимологічний словник т.2, с.288](http://litopys.org.ua/djvu/etymolog_slovnyk.htm) також пояснює походження імені **ІВАН**:
[image]

Як стає зрозуміло з цих словникових статей, обидва імені мають спільне походження, а саме - грецьке. Однак, це 2 різних імені, 2 різні словникові статті. **Іван** - через церковнослов'янську  запозичене в давньоруську з грецької, Ян -запозичення з польської, і пов'язане з лат. "Іоанн". Саме цими різними шляхами запозичення можна пояснити таке розгалуження на -**ян**- і -**іван**-.

Comment: Дав свій голос за вашу відповідь. Попрошу лише верхню світлину замінити на ідентичну з додатковим рядком згори, щоб було зрозуміло, що це таки запозичення з польської, а не якоїсь іншої мови.

Answer (score 2):

Із словника-довідника "[Власні імена людей](http://irbis-nbuv.gov.ua/cgi-bin/ua/elib.exe?Z21ID=&I21DBN=UKRLIB&P21DBN=UKRLIB&S21STN=1&S21REF=10&S21FMT=online_book&C21COM=S&S21CNR=20&S21P01=0&S21P02=0&S21P03=FF=&S21STR=ukr0001272)" Л. Г. Скрипник, Н. П. Дзятківська

[image: Іванна]

[image: Яна]

Дивимося чоловічі імена, від яких утворилися жіночі в цьомуж словнику-довіднику

[image: Іван]

[image: Ян]

***Отже, Іванна, Яна, Яніна - це три різні імені, хоч і мають спільні скорочувальні та пестливі форми.***
Якщо в різних документах однієї особи вказані різні імена - [згідно статті 28](http://radnuk.info/komentar/chky/chky-knuga1/chky-knuga1-pozd2/98-tsk-glava4/1750--28---.html) Цивільного кодексу України - це вважається помилкою. Ім'я повино бути написане у всіх документах, однієї особи, однаково.

Оскільки, чоловічі імена, від яких утворилися жіночі мають різне походження так і почалося розгалуження на *ян-* і *іван-*.